# Symfony2 Monolog to Email Errors why swiftmailer.transport.real is non-existent service

Tags: php, symfony, service, swiftmailer

after updating symfony from `2.3` to `2.4` i got `ServiceNotFoundException`

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'The service "monolog.handler.mojhandler" has a dependency on a non-existent service "swiftmailer.transport.real".' in E:\wamp\www\project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 59
```

here is my config_prod.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      streamed
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        mail:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      buffered
            channels: ["!app"] # Dont log app because we dont' want 404 errors sending
        buffered:
            type:    buffer
            handler: mojhandler
        mojhandler:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %mojhandler_logger_email%
            to_email:   %mojhandler_logger_email%
            subject:    "[Panel] An Error Occurred!"
            level:      debug
```

and here is my swiftmailer configuration from config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    port:      %mailer_port%
    auth_mode: %mailer_auth_mode%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you try an `app/console container:debug --env=prod | grep mail` and check the output? You should see all services that are defined and contain the word mail.

Comment: here you go: http://pastebin.com/GVKwv9ct, btw command is only available in degub mode

Comment: That's weird. What's the value of your `%mailer_transport%` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be an error when upgrading to Monolog Bundle 2.5.0 that causes this if you do not have the 'spool' config value set under the swiftmailer configuration.

Comment: it's a correct answer, i manage to fix it long before you answered. hope it will help others!

Answer (score 7):

It seems indeed to be a bug if we dont set the 'spool' config value in the swiftmailer config.

To solve this I had to create the missing services myself (since I don't want to use spool) in one of my services.yml:

```
swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker:
    class: Swift_Transport_SimpleMailInvoker

swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher:
    class: Swift_Events_SimpleEventDispatcher

swiftmailer.transport.real:
    class: Swift_Transport_MailTransport
    arguments: [@swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker, @swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher]
```