# Symfony ~2.4 composer update swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real dependency exception

Tags: symfony, composer-php, swiftmailer

After composer update, i started getting error message:

The service "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real" has a dependency on a non-existent service "swiftmailer.transport.buffer"

After bit of research i found solutions:

- http://error.bengtuo.com/page/13489.html
- [Symfony2 Monolog to Email Errors why swiftmailer.transport.real is non-existent service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074756/symfony2-monolog-to-email-errors-)

Basically what they offer is to set swiftmail parameter `spool: {type: memory}` or create service description manually

I've added sppol to all configs: config.yml, config_test.yml, config_dev.yml but that did not helped. Then i've added entries in one of my bundles services.yml

```
swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker:
    class: Swift_Transport_SimpleMailInvoker

swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher:
    class: Swift_Events_SimpleEventDispatcher

swiftmailer.transport.real:
    class: Swift_Transport_MailTransport
    arguments: [@swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker, @swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher]
```

but that did not solved my problem ether.

My composer file looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/Wsfx22Lg

Any advice how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try my variant, it works for me:

```
swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker: 
    class: Swift_Transport_SimpleMailInvoker

swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher: 
    class: Swift_Events_SimpleEventDispatcher

swiftmailer.replacementfactory:
    class: Swift_StreamFilters_StringReplacementFilterFactory

swiftmailer.transport.buffer:
    class: Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer
    arguments: [@swiftmailer.replacementfactory]

swiftmailer.transport.real:
    class: Swift_Transport_MailTransport 
    arguments: [@swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker, @swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your service.yml: worked for me

```
swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker: 
    class: Swift_Transport_SimpleMailInvoker

swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher: 
    class: Swift_Events_SimpleEventDispatcher

swiftmailer.transport.buffer: 
    class: Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer

swiftmailer.transport.real:
    class: Swift_Transport_MailTransport 
    arguments: [@swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker, @swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher]
```

I used part of the previous answer and worked it. Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

The **[xml](/questions/tagged/xml) version** of [@*Yury Pliashkou's*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849838/365265) answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>

        <service id="swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker" class="Swift_Transport_SimpleMailInvoker" />

        <service id="swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher" class="Swift_Events_SimpleEventDispatcher" />

        <service id="swiftmailer.replacementfactory" class="Swift_StreamFilters_StringReplacementFilterFactory" />

        <service id="swiftmailer.transport.buffer" class="Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer">
            <argument type="service" id="swiftmailer.replacementfactory"></argument>
        </service>

        <service id="swiftmailer.transport.real" class="Swift_Transport_MailTransport">
            <argument type="service" id="swiftmailer.transport.simplemailinvoker"></argument>
            <argument type="service" id="swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher"></argument>
        </service>

    </services>

</container>
```